# How to use multiple titles css

Tags: html, css, fonts, header

I want to use in my css different titles/headers, with the same font but with different font size, etc. I have this:

```
#titulo1{
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-height:50px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

#titulo2{
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-height: 40px;
  color: #73bd34;
}

#titulo3{
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-height: 30px;
  color: #5f9b16;
}

#titulo4{
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-height: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000000;
}
```

Now I want to use some titles to some divs and others to anothers.
Like this:

```
.slogan #titulo1{
...
}

.pesquisa #titulo3{
...
}
```

But it doesn't work, I can only make it work by using it in my html file like this:

```
<div class="slogan" id="titulo1">
```

Yeah, I had already visited this page:http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp and still nothing

Comment: I suggest you take a look in documentation at CSS selectors: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/css/611/selectors#t=201702091124578300889

Comment: You need to use classes instead of ids - ids should be unique.  And if you are wanting to change the element with a class of slogan and id of titulo1, you need to remove the space between the selector: `#titulo1.slogan` (I have swapped the order as I prefer ids to come first as they have greater weight).  [This is a good article about css specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use selector that select all elements that id starts with "titulo"

```
[id^="titulo"] {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

#titulo1{
  font-size: 40px;
  font-height:50px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

#titulo2{
  font-size: 30px;
  font-height: 40px;
  color: #73bd34;
}

#titulo3{
  font-size: 20px;
  font-height: 30px;
  color: #5f9b16;
}

#titulo4{
  font-size: 13px;
  font-height: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000000;
}
```

Definition `.slogan #titulo1` has no sense, because id is unique identifier, so `#titulo1` means the same.

anyway selector of particular element with several classes, e.g. `<div class="class1 class2">` will look `.class1.class2` (without space between class names) or `div.class1.class2`

Answer (score 0):

Its the space in the css, that makes it difficult . Lets see :

Notice this:

```
  .slogan  #titulo1{
      color:red; 
   }
```

This will work for follwoing  html structure

```
<div class="slogan">
   <div id="titulo1">
   </div>
</div>
```

Now Notice this:

```
.slogan#titulo1{
    color:red;
 }
```

This will work for follwoing  html structure

```
<div class="slogan" id="titulo1">

</div>
```

**Did you notice the space in the css, if you put an space that mean they are in different element**

Answer (score 0):

Use The following. Hope your problem will be solved :)

```
<div class="slogan">
  <div id="titulo1">
    --------
    --------
  </div>
</div>
```